# jQuery waypoint not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I am using animate.css to add some simple animations to my website. I want some information to fade in when it hits a waypoint, however it seems that the waypoint function is not working at all.

jQuery

```
$('.events-wp').waypoint(function(direction) {
       $('.events-wp').addClass('animated fadeIn');
    });
```

CSS

```
.events-wp {
    opacity: 0;
}
.events-wp.animated {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group events-wp" id="accordion">
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked using this. Couldn't get fadeIn to work, but that i part i would likely do in CSS instead. (is it transform or transition i think). Note that i changed the animated class name from a dot to a "-". I think the dots confused the JS.

```
    var $events = $('.events-wp');

 $events.waypoint(function(direction) {
   $events.addClass('events-wp-animated');
});
```

this video is pretty good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hPVpVtgle4